# Standalone Power Automate per user plan for Premuim connectors

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, administration, flow, power-platform

I need a connector to be able to call any HTTP endpoint to retrieve some data and push them to SharePoint.

I'm looking at the HTTP connector which is a premium connector
I was thinking of going for a per user plan in Power Automate and  assign a specific account to run the processes.

Will this method work and does this make sense? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a Power automate flow which will be ran using only one user account, it will work with per user plan in Power Automate.

Check below Microsoft official documentations for more information:

1. [Frequently asked questions about Power Automate licensing - Which Power Automate licenses do I need?](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/admin/power-automate-licensing/faqs?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#which-power-automate-licenses-do-i-need)
2. [Types of Power Automate licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/admin/power-automate-licensing/types?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Power Automate pricing](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/pricing/)